# Google visualization data table-getFilteredRows method

Tags: google-visualization

Im trying to filter column 'time' in visualization data table using getFilteredRows(filters) method.I provided column value with minimum and maximum values as,

```
var timesheet_dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data, 0.6);
var time_filter = timesheet_dataTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 3, minValue: '2:28 PM', maxValue: '3:01 PM'}]);
```

and then created data view with setRows method to display the data but the table displayed without filtering the data.I checked with other column values and received proper output.So whether 'timeofday' data type  is supported in this type of filters?
Is there any other method to filter column based on time?

**Update:** 
This is the code for formatting and passing value to the visualization table.Value of variable *startTime* will be like '14:28:12'.

```
val datetimeStart: String = "Date(0,0,0,"
val datetimeEnd: String = ")"
val simpleDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH,mm,ss")
Json.obj("v" -> JsString(datetimeStart + (simpleDateTimeFormat.format(tsl.startTime)).toString() + datetimeEnd))
```

before displaying in visualization table i have used formatter as:

```
var formatter_short1 = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern:'h:mm aa'});
formatter_short1.format(timesheet_dataTable,3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "timeofday" data type is supported by the filter method, you just need to use it correctly:

```
// filter column 3 from 2:28PM to 3:01PM
var time_filter = timesheet_dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 3,
    minValue: [14, 28, 0, 0],
    maxValue: [15, 1, 0, 0]
}]);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(timesheet_dataTable);
view.setRows(time_filter);
```

Make sure you are using the view you create to draw your chart, instead of the DataTable:

```
chart.draw(view, options);
```

**[edit - example for filtering "datetime" type column]**

```
// filter column 3 from 2:28PM to 3:01PM
var time_filter = timesheet_dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 3,
    minValue: new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 28, 0, 0),
    maxValue: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0)
}]);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(timesheet_dataTable);
view.setRows(time_filter);
```

Comment: :I tried with above steps it doesn't work.Forgot to mention that i had applied date format for time to display in table as "var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern:'h:mm:ss aa'});".so from this i have to filter the table on basis of time column.

Comment: The formatter shouldn't make a difference.  I'll need to see a full code example demonstrating them problem in order to help you diagnose this; update your question with code.

Comment: Your data is using the "datetime" format, not the "timeofday" format (an array in the form `[hour, minute, second, millisecond]`), which is why the example I posted doesn't work for you.  If you change my example to filter with Date objects, it should work: `{column: 3, minValue: new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 28, 0, 0), maxValue: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0)}`.